# Divide window space in half for two widgets to have the same size

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want two Widgets/Layouts be next to each other (using QHBoxLayout) but they should have the same size (half the size of the window).

It should look like this:
[image: like this] but I want the button to be smaller (the button is contained in another Layout) while the list widget remains the same size.

I tried using minimumSize, sizeHint, stretch, etc. but it never worked.
My code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw


class SelectView(qtw.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.width = 750
        self.height = 500

        self.setGeometry(200, 200, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle("SelectView")

        self.list_widget = qtw.QListWidget()
        self.list_widget.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width//2, self.height)

        for i in range(100):
            self.list_widget.addItem(qtw.QListWidgetItem(f"something{i}"))

        left_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()

        btn = qtw.QPushButton("button")
        # I'm using this to show you that I want the widgets/layout
        # to be half the size of the window
        btn.setFixedWidth(375)  

        left_layout.addWidget(btn)

        h_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        h_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        h_layout.addLayout(left_layout)
        self.setLayout(h_layout)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SelectView()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

edit:

```
self.list_widget.setMinimumSize(self.width//2, self.height)
```

would do the job if the window had a fixed size.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the stretch factor:

```
h_layout.addWidget(self.list_widget, stretch=1)
h_layout.addLayout(left_layout, stretch=1)
```

**Note:** Remove `btn.setFixedWidth(...)`

Comment: I tried that too but if I do that, it doesn't do anything. If I set my button size to 120 for example, the left layout collapses and the list takes about 80% of the space, instead of the desired 50%

Comment: @Ahiru Why do you set a fixed size for the button? remove `btn.setFixedWidth(....)`

Comment: If I remove the fixedWidth, it works. But I'd like to have some free space left and right of the button. Is that possible?

Comment: @Ahiru I do not understand you, explain yourself better.

Comment: @Ahiru try with: `left_layout.setContentsMargins(100, 0, 100, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

SInce you have specified the size of the window, no need for the fixed width sizes you defined for the widgets. Instead do something like this:

```
layout = QHBoxLayout()

layout.addWidget(widget1)
layout.addWidget(widget2)

widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(layout)
self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```